# cannot cronify with whenever - incompatible library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, whenever

We use whenever to manage cron, recently, when we deploy, we get this error:

```
    4: from /var/www/sites/opencaseware-prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/chronic-0.10.2/lib/chronic.rb:1:in `require'
    3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/time.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/time.rb:3:in `require'
    1: from /var/www/sites/opencaseware-prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/www/sites/opencaseware-prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date.rb:4:in `require': incompatible library version - /var/www/sites/opencaseware-prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/date-3.3.3/lib/date_core.so (LoadError)
```

this just recently started happening.  we are using ruby 2.7.6 and rails 5.2 on ubuntu 18.10

thanks for any help,
kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bundle pristine
```

fixes this

more filler to hit the minimum required by so